# p-test and basic probability

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have a basic question on p-tests (it is the first time I use them). Imagine having a basket with 70 orange balls and 30 blue balls. The probability to pick to pick an orange ball is 0.7 and the probability to get a blue ball is 0.3.

Now imagine I have a second basket and by picking 10 balls I have to determine wether or not the second basket has the same proportion of orange and blue balls. I could define a random variable such that X(blue) = 0 and X(orange) = 1, the probability distribution of this random variable has $\mu = 0.7$ and $\sigma = 0.483$.

The outcome of the test is 10 orange balls.

1) The probability of picking 10 orange balls in a row is $0.7^{10}=0.028$. This gives a good indication that the second basket has more orange balls than the first.

2) Using p-test: The sample mean of my sample is $\mu_s = 0$. I could make the null hypothesis ($H_0$) that the baskets are the same, hence $\bar \mu_s = \mu$ and $\sigma_s = \sigma$. The sample mean random variable has a standard deviation $\sigma_\mu = \sigma/\sqrt{10}$ (using CLT). Hence, the probability of getting mean $\mu_s$ under $H_0$ is given by:

$$ 2\phi\left(\frac{\mu_s-\bar \mu_s}{\sigma_\mu}\right) = 2\phi(-4.58)=4.6 10^{-6}$$

This p-value rejects the null hypothesis and therefore the baskets are different.

The question is: how are these two methods and probabilities related?

Is it wrong to estimate the standard deviation of my sample as being $\sigma$ in method (2)? I am doing this way because the std of my sample is zero.

Any better method to solve this problem?

Comment: 1) Yup, quantity -> proportion 2) I don't expect to be the same, but I don't understand how (if) they are related. I rephrase the question. 3) What is the correct notation? $\mu_{\bar X}$? 4) I am not sure I understand your last comment.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment.** Thanks for the clarification. But this is still somewhat of a
tangled mess. Below, I am not necessarily trying to give answers, as much
as I am trying to draw some of the distinctions that need to be made
before you try to compute answers of your own. I hope some of my comments are
helpful.

Let $X$ be the number of orange
balls seen when $n = 10$ balls are drawn at random, with replacement, from
an urn with 70% orange balls. Then $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 10, p = .7)$
and $P(X = 10) = .7^{10} = 0.028$ as you say. The distribution of $X$ is shown by the
heights of the black balls in the figure below. If you tried to approximate
this using a normal distribution then the 'best fitting' formal distribution
has $\mu = np = 7$ and $\sigma = \sqrt{npq} \approx 1.449.$ The denisty
finction of $\mathsf{Norm}(7, 1.449)$ is also shown.

[image]

If you use the normal curve, with continuity correction) to approximation $P(X = 10)$ you would get
the area under the normal curve to the right of $x = 9.5$ (shown as
a vertical dashed line). As you can see, the fit is not perfect. The
normal approximation gives $P(X = 10) \approx 0.042 > 0.028.$

*Note:* If sampling is *without* replacement, then you should use a hypergeometric
distribution. If you *assume* that the second basket also
has 100 balls (70 orange), then you would obtain $P(X = 10) = 0.023 \ne 0.028.$

I believe your last computation is an attempt to test whether $p = 0.7,$ based
the proportion $\hat p = X/n,$ where $X = 0$ orange balls. This
seems inappropriate, and I am not surprised it gives nowhere near
the same numerical result as above.

Comment: Thanks, I know I am still very messy, I had a probability&stat course but that was a long time ago :). I'll read your answer tomorrow morning, but what I was trying to use was the fact that the sample mean has normal distribution and a kind of t-test. I got inspired from this exercise: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FtlH4svqx4

Comment: Don't see a t test here. Maybe a z-test of $H_0: p = .7$ vs. $H_a: p \ne .7$ with statistic $\hat p = X/n.$ Then reject $H_0$ if $|Z| > 1.96,$ where $Z = (\hat p - .7)/SE$ and $SE = \sqrt{.7(.3)/n}.$ Not clear how many orange balls $X$ out of $n = 10$ for your data. If that makes any sense, try to be more specific about what data and what $H_0$ and what $H_a$ to test. Will check back in 10 hrs or so.  Once we settle for sure on what you're trying to do, it can't be impossibly complicated. (Also, is it sampling _with_ replacement? Or _without_?)

Comment: Still didn't have the chance to check in detail! I'll do that in 12h. I'll rephrase the question!